Why does TypeScript think `(s: string, n: number) => (s || undefined) && n` can return empty string?
I am writing a function that returns undefined when an input is falsy. In TypeScript 5.6.2, I can't get the following example past the type checker:
// Return type: number | "" | undefined
const f1 = (s: string, n: number) => (s || undefined) && n;

// Type 'number | "" | undefined' is not assignable to type 'number | undefined'.
//   Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.(2322)
const x: number | undefined = f1("a", 1);

Playground
The inferred return type says that f1 could return an empty string. This is annoying because I need to handle a string return type that is impossible. I think the return type should be number | undefined instead.
The same thing happens when the string and number are switched:
// Return type: string | 0 | undefined
const f2 = (s: string, n: number) => (n || undefined) && s;

When I use a ternary operator or coerce to boolean, the return type is inferred correctly:
// Return type: number | undefined
const f3 = (s: string, n: number) => (s ? true : undefined) && n;

// Return type: number | undefined
const f4 = (s: string, n: number) => (!!s || undefined) && n;


Why are you writing that at all? s ? n : undefined has the right types and more clearly expresses the logic than anything you've proposed. (As to why that's the result, it might be clearer stepwise: https://tsplay.dev/NBrJpN)

The answer is that TS lacks negated types (as requested in ms/TS#4196). So s || undefined should be of a type like (string & not "") | undefined. But TS has no way to represent that and can only model that as string, and (s || undefined) & n is therefore of type "" | number | undefined instead of type number | undefined.  Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write an answer or find a suitable duplicate; if not, what am I missing?

"Why are you writing that at all?" --
@jonrsharpe The question contains the simplest expression that can reproduce the issue. It has been simplified to the point that, as you mentioned, there is no reason to write it in practice. So I guess it is more of an academic exercise.

@jcalz Yeah that makes sense. Sounds like it is something that can't be expressed in the type system.

TypeScript's type system isn't expressive enough to represent "a truthy string" in a way that has an effect on control flow analysis. Only the empty string of the literal type "" is falsy, so all strings except the empty string are truthy.  But in order to say "all strings except the empty string" TypeScript would need something like subtraction types as requested in microsoft/TypeScript#4183 or negated types as requested in microsoft/TypeScript#4916.  It has neither of these. So there's no string ~ "" or string & not "".
If there were such a type, then presumably s || undefined would be of type (string & not "") | undefined (since logical OR (||) evaluates to its first operand if it is truthy, or its second operand otherwise, thus you get the truthy part of the first operand unioned with the second operand).  And then (s || undefined) && n would be of type number | ("" & not "") | undefined which would simplify to number | undefined (since logical AND (&&) evaluates to its first operand if it is falsy, or its second operand otherwise, thus you get the falsy part of the first operand unioned with the second operand).
What actually happens is that s || undefined is of the type string | undefined, and the fact that it cannot be "" is lost. And then (s || undefined) && number evaluates to the falsy part of the first operand (string | undefined) union  since string | undefined is falsy if and only if its value is "" | undefined, that's what you get unioned with number.  TypeScript loses track of "cannot be """.

This also explains how 0 shows up when string and number are switched. 0 is the only falsy number, but there is no number ~ 0 or number & not 0 to express truthy numbers.

To clarify your question, you're asking that since f5 has the following return value:
// Return type: string | undefined
const f5 = (s: string) => (s || undefined);

Then why does f1 has the following return type, if all we're doing is using the logical AND operator (&&)?
// Return type: number | "" | undefined
const f1 = (s: string, n: number) => (s || undefined) && n;


The answer lies in the definition of the logical AND operator:

Logical AND (&&) evaluates operands from left to right, returning immediately with the value of the first falsy operand it encounters; if all values are truthy, the value of the last operand is returned.

In our case, we have (s || undefined) & n. This translates to a type of (string | undefined) logically ANDed with a number type. Looking at the string | undefined operand, possible falsy values are undefined and "" (empty string). When we apply the logical AND operator, if (s || undefined) results in a falsy value (one of undefined or ""), that falsy value will be the result of the logical AND.
These falsy values are logically ANDed with the number type in the second operand to get undefined | "" | number.
An example that proves this out is removing the logical OR:
// Return type: number | ""
const f6 = (s: string, n: number) => s && n;


To explicitly type your function f1, just narrow it manually:
// Return type: number | undefined
const f1 = (s: string, n: number) => ((s || undefined) && n) as number | undefined;


I'm pretty sure they are really asking why f5 doesn't return TruthyString | undefined where TruthyString is some conceptual equivalent to string & not "". Of course (Math.random()<0.5 ? s : undefined) && n should return "" | undefined | number, but s || undefined cannot be "".
